# Why does this code segment, used to reverse print a singly connected linked list, not work as expected?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

```
int printRev(void *l)
{
    list_sll *list= (list_sll *)l;
    int i= list->noOfNodes-1;
    node_sll *subject= malloc(sizeof(node_sll));
    subject->next= list->start;
    node_sll *front= NULL;  /*node directly in front of subject*/
    do {
        while(subject->next!=front)
            subject= subject->next;
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, subject->data);
        front= subject;
        subject->next= list->start;
        --i;
    }
    while(front!=list->start);
    subject= NULL;
    free(subject);
    return 0;
}
```

I am passing the address of a structure(definitions given below) used to store the required details of a linked list(already created) to the printRev() function, which accepts it as a pointer to void.
Here is the minimal viable code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_sll
{
int data;
struct node_sll *next;
} node_sll;

typedef struct list_sll
{
struct node_sll *start;
int noOfNodes;
} list_sll;

int printlist(void *);
int printRev(void *);
int insert(void *, int);

int main(void)
{
    list_sll list1;
    list1.noOfNodes= 1;
    printf("Creating the first node\nEnter the data\n");
    int d;
    scanf("%d", &d);
    node_sll node1;
    node1.data= d;
    node1.next= NULL;
    list1.start= &node1;
    int choice;
    do {
        printf( "\nEnter:\n1. INSERT: to insert the node\n"
        "2. PRINT: print the list\n"
        "3. PRINT@rev: print the list in reverse order\n"
        "0. QUIT: quit this menu\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the node data\n");
                insert(&list1, list1.noOfNodes);
                break;
            case 2:
                printlist(&list1);
                break;
            case 3:
                printRev(&list1);
                break;
        } 
    }
    while(choice);
    return 0;
}

int printlist(void *l)
{
    struct list_sll *list= (list_sll *)l;
    struct node_sll *p= list->start;
    int count= 0;
    printf("no of nodes: %d\n", list->noOfNodes);
    while(p!=NULL && count < list->noOfNodes) {
        printf("%d. %d\n", count, p->data);
        p=p->next;
        ++count;
    }
    return 0;
}

int insert(void *l, int pos)
{
    struct list_sll *list= (list_sll *)l;
    struct node_sll *current= malloc(sizeof(node_sll));
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &(current->data));
    current->next= list->start;
    struct node_sll *prev_node= NULL;
    while(pos--) {
    prev_node= current->next;
    current->next= current->next->next;
    }
    if(prev_node==NULL)
        list->start= current;
    else
        prev_node->next= current;
    ++(list->noOfNodes);
    printf("No of nodes %d\n", list->noOfNodes);
    return 0;
}

int printRev(void *l)
{
    list_sll *list= (list_sll *)l;
    int i= list->noOfNodes-1;
    node_sll *subject= malloc(sizeof(node_sll));
    subject->next= list->start;
    node_sll *front= NULL;  /*node directly in front of subject*/
    do {
        while(subject->next!=front)
            subject= subject->next;
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, subject->data);
        front= subject;
        subject->next= list->start;
        --i;
    }
    while(front!=list->start);
    subject= NULL;
    free(subject);
    return 0;
}
```

When I invoke printRev( ) function, the reversed list gets printed but for some reason that I can't figure out, the list elements change after the printing is done. All the nodes now store the same data which is equal to the value of data of the first node. Why is data getting changed when I am changing only some pointers?
In an attempt to debug I created a list(nodes- 10, 20, 30, 40) and added some lines of code in printRev( ):

```
int printRev(void *l)
{
    list_sll *list= (list_sll *)l;
    int i= list->noOfNodes-1;
    node_sll *subject= malloc(sizeof(node_sll));
    subject->next= list->start;
    node_sll *front= NULL;  /*node directly in front of subject*/
    do {
        while(subject->next!=front)
            subject= subject->next;
        printf("%d. %d\n", i, subject->data);

        //printing current list status
        printf("%d", list->start->data);
        printf("%d", list->start->next->data);
        printf("%d", list->start->next->next->data);
        printf("%d", list->start->next->next->next->data);

        front= subject;
        subject->next= list->start;
        --i;
    }
    while(front!=list->start);
    subject= NULL;
    free(subject);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I get when I invoke this function:

> 3.40
>   10
>   20
>   30
>   40
>
> 2.30
>   10
>   20
>   30
>   40
>
> 1.20
>   10
>   20
>   30
>   10
>
> 0.10
>   10
>   20
>   10
>   20

I am unable to figure out the problem. Please help.

Comment: Is your cat dead on the spacebar?

Comment: Mind to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Inside the do-while: I do not think that this: `while(subject->next!=front) subject= subject->next;` does what you think it does.  It can be rewritten as `subject = front;`

Comment: @grochmal It stops when `subject->next == front`, not when `subject == front`

Comment: @Peter will this help to reproduce?

Comment: @Nityesh Agarwal, I meant MCVE, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, i.e. a single complete program that we can copy-paste and run.

Comment: MCVE has been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the function already has undefined behavior because it has return type `int` but returns nothing.

There is no need to allocate dynamically the node `subject`. It can be declared as an object of the structure type.

This do-while loop also can result in undefined behavior if the list is empty

```
do {
    while(subject->next!=front)
        subject= subject->next;
    printf("%d. %d\n", i, subject->data);
    //...
}
while(front!=list->start);
```

because there will be an attempt to access values for a null pointer.

Also in this do-while loop the pointer `subject` is changed

```
do {
    while(subject->next!=front)
        subject= subject->next;
    // ...
    subject->next= list->start;
    // ...
}
```

Thus the original list is also changed.

These statements

```
subject= NULL;
free(subject);
```

result in memory leak because the original dynamically allocated object pointed to by the pointer `subject` was not freed.

If to use your approach then the function can look the following way (without testing).

```
void printRev( void *l )
{
    list_sll *list = ( list_sll * )l;

    int i = list->noOfNodes;

    node_sll subject = { 0, list->start };

    node_sll *front = NULL;  /*node directly in front of subject*/

    while ( i != 0 )
    {
        node_sll *current = &subject;

        while ( current->next != front ) current = current->next;

        --i;

        printf( "%d. %d\n", i, current->data );

        front = current;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the do-while loop of my code, I am only changing where the subject pointer points to. So why should it change what is actually stored at that address?

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal In the loop the subject pointer also is changed in each iteration subject= subject->next;
. It does not have the initial value.

Comment: yes exactly. It now stores the address of the next node. That shouldn't change the data. Anyways, isn't this how you traverse a linked list implemented using pointers?

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal The problem is not in how you traverse a list. The problem is that after that you mistakenly assume that it has the initial value and thus you change the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this statement `subject->next= list->start;` You are altering the list when you are doing it.

You can modify it in the following way

```
int printRev(void *l)
{
 list_sll *list= (list_sll *)l;
 int i= list->noOfNodes-1;
 node_sll *subject = list->start;
 node_sll *front= NULL;  /*node directly in front of subject*/
 do {
     while(subject->next!=front)
         subject= subject->next;
     printf("%d. %d\n", i, subject->data);
     front= subject;
     subject= list->start;
     --i;
 }
 while(front!=list->start);
}
```

And please consider what to do in case the list is empty as Vlad said